# LinageOS update reboots into TWRP

Tags: twrp

I downloaded the LinageOS update (linage-14.1-20181107-nightly-*-signed.zip) and rebooted to complete the install. It booted into TWRP (3.2.3-0). What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually install the update by

1. Click `Install`.
2. Select the file `/data/linageos_updates/linage-*.zip`.

Comment: Nice work. ....